# Redirecting to a url with query params and assigning values to reactive form from the query params not working - Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm redirecting to a URL with query params and assigning the values from the query params to the form using setValue but value is not displaying initially but displaying after refresh.

Getting values from query params and assigning to form:

```
constructor(private fromBuilder: FormBuilder, private _API: RestService, private storageService: StorageService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {

    if (!this.formsInitialized) this.initForms()

    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {

      if (params.user) {
        this.registerForm['controls']['cpName'].setValue(JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(params.user)).name, { onlySelf: false })
        this.registerForm['controls']['cpEmail'].setValue(JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(params.user)).email, { onlySelf: false })
      }

    })

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  initForms() {

    this.formsInitialized = true

    this.registerForm = this.fromBuilder.group({
      cpName: ['dfdfd', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(30), Validators.pattern(this.namePattern)]],
      cpEmail: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.emailPattern)]],
      dname: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(15), Validators.pattern(this.domainPattern)]],
      bname: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50), Validators.pattern(this.brandPattern)]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(15)]],
      token: [''],
      googleId: [''],
      imageUrl: [''],
    });

  }
```

Comment: Have you tried subscribing to query params in ngOnInit?

Comment: Tried but the same result

Comment: Your code looks pretty fine, could you reproduce in a stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the form before setting the values:

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {

      if (params.user) {
      this.initForms();
        this.registerForm['controls']['cpName'].setValue(JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(params.user)).name, { onlySelf: false })
        this.registerForm['controls']['cpEmail'].setValue(JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(params.user)).email, { onlySelf: false })
      }

    });
```